# Excepcion no controlada en la aplicación Acceso denegado System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005)

Tags: c#

Cuando quiero que mi aplicación se cierre quiero que al cerrarse mate también otro proceso del equipo.

Lo que he intentado hacer es lo siguiente:

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        
        
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("x"))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Pero cuando cierro la aplicación me da el error que he mencionado en el título.
Me cierra la aplicación del equipo que quiero cerrar pero mi aplicación no se cierra y sale el error.

```
Consulte el final de este mensaje para obtener más detalles sobre cómo invocar a la depuración 
Just-In-Time (JIT) en lugar de a este cuadro de diálogo.

************** Texto de la excepción **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Acceso denegado
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill()
```

Si alguien sabe porque ocurre esto o como puedo arreglarlo comenten por favor. Gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Parece ser que no tenes permisos para hacer el kill del otro proceso... un poco mas de informacion vendria bien...

Comment: Sí, es un proceso asincrónico que deriva del programa, puedes usar GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que quitar el `Application.Exit();` Si lo pones la aplicacion vuelve a llamar a `Main_FormClosing()` y vuelve a buscar al proceso 'x' y trata de cerrarlo otra vez con `process.Kill();` y es alli donde sale el error.

Te pongo un codigo improvisado para que veas que se llama al `Main_FormClosing()` mas de una vez si usas dentro el `Application.Exit();`:

```
int llamada = 0;
    private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            llamada++;

            if (llamada > 1) MessageBox.Show("ya se llamo mas de una vez para cerrar");

            Application.Exit();

        }
```

Cada vez que se llame a `Main_FormClosing()` la variable usada como contador se incrementará en 1
Si se llama mas de una vez al metodo como en este caso sale el mensaje de aviso.